# How can I have a scrollable body with fixed header and footer inside a container div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one container `<div>` with two children `<div>` elements inside of it. I want to place one child `<div>` at the top and other child `<div>` at the bottom of the container `<div>`. The middle part (the content) should scroll between the top and bottom child `<div>` elements.

I want both children `<div>` elements inside the container `<div>` to have a fixed position and the content should scroll without scrolling both top and bottom div.

I'd like a solution using CSS or jQuery, please. For a JSFiddle example, see my comment below.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0xr2nwg2/9/

Answer (score 2):

This should be fairly straightforward. **[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0xr2nwg2/12/)**.

First, I put your loose div text inside a `<p>` element, and removed the default margin of that `<p>` element. Then, I changed the `overflow: scroll;` to `overflow-y: scroll;` and moved it to that new `<p>` element. Finally, I gave the `<p>` element an explicit `height: 300px;`, which is the height of the parent element, minus the height of the header and footer.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">inside1 Top should not scroll</div>
    <p>Your Text Here</p>
    <div class="inside2">inside 2 Bottom should not scroll</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outside {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.outside p {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 0;
    height: 300px;
}
.inside {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 50px;
}
.inside2 {
    bottom: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Ok thats really good to understand. But can you do the same thing without using <p> element means using what I used 'outside', 'inside' and 'inside2' element.

Comment: Thanks in advance sir. You can use may be jQuery for that.

Comment: @user2668276 I think you would need to use some kind of JavaScript for that. If this answer helped you, don't forget to upvote and/or click that checkmark, to let others know that it is helpful!